# How to fix firebase problem: "There was an unknown error while creating the project. Try again."?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

I tried to start a new project with Firebase and Android Studio. But while creating new project from firebase console it shows error again and again saying that "There was an unknown error while creating the project. Try again." **How can I get rid of this?**

I tried to start a new project from different mails and from android studio also(tools->firebase->Authentication->Connect your app with firebase), but it didn't work and showing unknown problems.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Console is in issue now, please check the status page.

[Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but what to do now?